# golang: GET request for presigned url of S3 object with SSE fails with 403 error

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

I'm getting 403 Forbidden HTTP response when I make a `GET` request to a presigned url generated by the AWS `Presign` method in Go.

The error message is:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method

`X-Amz-SignedHeaders` is: `host;x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm;x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key;x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key-md5`

I'm writing the object to S3 like this:

```golang
type DocumentStore struct {
    bucketName               string
    bucketEncryptionKeyAlias string
    aws                      *session.Session
}

func (s *DocumentStore) PutDocument(ctx context.Context, envelope []byte, metadata map[string]string) (PutDocumentResult, error) {
    uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(s.aws)

    var objectKey = uuid.New().String()

    if _, err := uploader.UploadWithContext(ctx, &s3manager.UploadInput{
        Bucket:               aws.String(s.bucketName),
        Key:                  aws.String(objectKey),
        ContentType:          aws.String("application/octet-stream"),
        Body:                 bytes.NewReader(envelope),
        ServerSideEncryption: aws.String(s3.ServerSideEncryptionAwsKms),
        SSEKMSKeyId:          aws.String(s.bucketEncryptionKeyAlias),
        Metadata:             aws.StringMap(metadata),
    }); err != nil {
        return PutDocumentResult{}, fmt.Errorf("put document failed on upload: %v", err.Error())
    }

    return PutDocumentResult{
        BucketName: s.bucketName,
        ObjectKey:  objectKey,
    }, nil
}
```

I'm signing the url like this:

```golang
func (s *DocumentStore) NewSignedGetURL(ctx context.Context, objectKey string, ttl time.Duration) (string, error) {
    svc := s3.New(s.aws)

    req, _ := svc.GetObjectRequest(&s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(s.bucketName),
        Key: aws.String(objectKey),
        SSECustomerKey: aws.String(s.bucketEncryptionKeyAlias),
        SSECustomerAlgorithm: aws.String(s3.ServerSideEncryptionAwsKms),
    })

    url, err := req.Presign(ttl)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("failed to presign GetObjectRequest for key %q: %v", objectKey, err)
    }

    return url, nil
}
```

And I'm calling the methods like this:

```golang
result, err := target.PutDocument(context.TODO(), envelope, metadata)
if err != nil {
    t.Errorf("PutDocument failed: %v", err)
    return
}

getURL, err := target.NewSignedGetURL(context.TODO(), result.ObjectKey, time.Minute*5)
if err != nil {
    t.Errorf("failed to sign url: %v", err)
    return
}

req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", getURL, nil)
req.Header.Add("x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm", s3.ServerSideEncryptionAwsKms)
req.Header.Add("x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key", test.cfg.AWS.BucketKMSAlias)
req.Header.Add("x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key-md5", "")

resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req.WithContext(context.TODO()))
if err != nil {
    t.Errorf("failed to request object from signed url: %v", err)
    return
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    t.Errorf("failed to read object stream from S3: %v", err)
    return
}

if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
    t.Errorf("failed to get object. Http status: %s(%d)\n%s", resp.Status, resp.StatusCode, data)
    return
}
```

I can read the download the file from the `aws cli` like this:

```
aws --profile dispatcher_stage --region us-east-1 s3 cp s3://[bucket-name]/0c/09179312-e283-431c-ab71-6a0c437177fe . --sse aws:kms --sse-kms-key-id alias/[key-alias-name]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out: the `GetObject` request doesn't need the SSE parameters as long as the user has `Decrypt` permission on the KMS key. Here's the relevant changes:

I'm now signing the url like this:

```
func (s *DocumentStore) NewSignedGetURL(ctx context.Context, objectKey string, ttl time.Duration) (string, error) {
    svc := s3.New(s.aws)

    req, _ := svc.GetObjectRequest(&s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(s.bucketName),
        Key: aws.String(objectKey),
    })

    url, err := req.Presign(ttl)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("failed to presign GetObjectRequest for key %q: %v", objectKey, err)
    }

    return url, nil
}
```

And I'm downloading the object like this:

```
getURL, err := target.NewSignedGetURL(context.TODO(), result.ObjectKey, time.Minute*5)
if err != nil {
    t.Errorf("failed to sign url: %v", err)
    return
}

req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", getURL, nil)
req.Header.Add("host", req.Host)

resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req.WithContext(context.TODO()))
if err != nil {
    t.Errorf("failed to request object from signed url: %v", err)
    return
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    t.Errorf("failed to read object stream from S3: %v", err)
    return
}
```